# ¿Cómo corregir el error ORA-311011 al consultar en Oracle con un campo Clob XML?

Tags: oracle, clob

Tengo el siguiente problema al realizar la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM w0089_ses_tablas
       WHERE existsnode(XMLTYPE(c0089_datos_xml), '/r/*') > 0;
```

Me sale el siguiente error cuando la tabla tiene muchos datos (hablo de casi 20709):

```
ORA-311011: Fallo en el análisis de XML
ORA-19202: Se ha producido un error en el procesamiento
LPX-00244: Invalid use of less-than('<') character (use lt;)
Error at line 1
  de XML
ORA-06512: en "SYS.XMLTYPE", linea 272
ORA-06512: en linea 1
```

con pocos insert en esa tabla sí funciona.

Comment: Suena a un XML malformado ¿se validan antes de insertarlos?.

Comment: Hola, es que ya están insertados, sabes alguna forma de validar esto.

Comment: Corresponde leer cada clob y pasarle alguna función propia que valide si está bien formado. Lo de que 20000 registros son muchos, no es real y no tiene relación con el fallo; una BD te va a procesar millones y millones de registros...

Answer (score 0):

El diagnóstico, como te dijeron en el comentario, es claro. Insertaron XML inválidos y ahora eso les revienta operaciones que suponen que funcionan para todos los datos.

Podrían crear una función que valide el contenido de cada registro en el campo clob

```
create function is_valid_xml(xml_param clob)
return int
as
  scratch xmltype;
begin
  select xmltype(xml_param) into scratch from dual;
  return 1;
exception
  when others then
    return 0;
end;
/
```

Luego, hacer un select para pintar el resultado de esa validación:

```
select 
    id, 
    is_valid_xml(campo_clob) as validacion
from tabla_con_clob;



ID | VALIDACION
---------------
 1 |     1
 2 |     0
...
```

Ahí van a ver qué registros son inválidos y les queda arreglarlos.

Para ser más felices en el futuro, podrían reusar la función en un trigger que valide BEFORE INSERT y rechace los XML inválidos.

Con base en [esta buena respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44133/34876).

Comment: Muchas Gracias, si era eso. Llevaba semanas buscando ese error.

Comment: @duvanleal con gusto. Si pruebas y te resuelve el lío, puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta.